# Img tag not working when i used local sytem path

Tags: html

```html
<body>
<img src="file:///G:/Flower_Fields_5.jpg"  width='300' height='190' />
</body>
```

**This image tag not working when i used above code**

Comment: Use relative pathes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="'file:///G:/Flower_Fields_5.jpg"  width='300' height='190' />
          ^
```

Extra single quote indicated above

Answer (score 1):

This should Work.

```
<img alt="" src="file:///C:/Users/Roby/Pictures/battlefield-3.jpg" width='300' height='190' />
```

Comment: ,sir i want access local system folder , because my image is stored there,not in web application folder

Answer (score 1):

Try

below one

Read about [absolute path and relative path](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) for images

```
<img src="http:\\localhost\site\img\mypicture.jpg"/>
```

Hope this should work